# How to programmatically switch display from standalone to fullscreen in PWA

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps

My PWA works as expected when I set the "display" of my manifest to "fullscreen" or "standalone". But, I want my users to be able to toggle back and forth in settings. Is there a way to switch this programmatically in JavaScript?

Answer (score 2):

try this if you want to be sure that it will work in all browsers.

```
function getFullScreen() {
    if (document.body.requestFullscreen) {
        document.body.requestFullscreen();
    } else if (document.body.mozRequestFullScreen) { /* Firefox */
        document.body.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (document.body.webkitRequestFullscreen) { /* Chrome, Safari and Opera */
        document.body.webkitRequestFullscreen();
    } else if (document.body.msRequestFullscreen) { /* IE/Edge */
        document.body.msRequestFullscreen();
    }
}
```

Comment: document.body.requestFullscreen() works on Windows Chrome and Android Chrome.  However, 
TypeScript under Ionic/Cordova does not recognize mozRequestFullScreen, webkitRequestFullscreen, msRequestFullscreen what do I need to import?

Comment: Hi @Meryan, you should try opening a new feed

Comment: Posting here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61283183/why-does-document-body-requestfullscreen-work-on-the-first-invocation-only

Answer (score 0):

use `document.body.requestFullscreen();`

```
var videoElement = document.getElementById("videoElement");
videoElement.requestFullscreen();
```

Check https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/native-hardware/fullscreen/